# Rails: Speed up closure tree insertion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tree, bulkinsert

I'm trying to use the [closure tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) gem for modelling some (ordered) nested data.

The issue I'm having is that when I go to insert records into the database (mysql) it is taking about 7 seconds to insert the 200 children (well, 400 inserts).

I'm about to go down the route of doing a straight bulk insert / raw sql in order to speed things up, though this means ensuring that I've got the hierarchy calls etc. correctly.

If anyone has a strategy out there for doing bulk inserts of children with `closure_tree` I'd love to see it.

My call to `closure_tree` is : `has_closure_tree order: 'position'`

I have also tried setting `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "set autocommit = 0;"` (makes no difference) and turning off `advisory_lock` (also makes no difference)

[edit] also tried wrapping in a `transaction` where I was adding the children, no joy either.

[edit] have opened an [issue](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree/issues/274) (which I hate doing, but I'm hoping there's a strategy I can follow for this)

Comment: Have you tried to wrap it into transaction?

Comment: Yip, have tried that. I don't quite understand why that would help, but yes, I tried it. I think it's simply that it's making 400 inserts (and also selecting to find the next positional id to use).

Comment: Transaction for N inserts\updates makes them faster for N like 100-1000. There are many explanations "why". But in your case may be gem is the source of the speed issue.